# Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The script below displays a shop cart using `ng-repeat`. For each element in the array, it shows the item name, its amount and the subtotal (`product.price * product.quantity`).

What is the simplest way for calculating the total price of repeated elements?

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="product in cart.products">
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{product.price * product.quantity}} €</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total :</td>
        <td></td> <!-- Here is the total value of my cart -->
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: angular.forEach($scope.cart.products, function(filterObj , filterKey) {  
                $scope.total += filterObj.product.price * filterObj.product.quantity;
            });

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25667437/59087

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat/25885501#25885501

Comment: Why dont you use tfoot-tag?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

In Template

```
<td>Total: {{ getTotal() }}</td>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cart.products.length; i++){
        var product = $scope.cart.products[i];
        total += (product.price * product.quantity);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: one downside to this is that it iterates over the collection twice.  this is fine for small collections, but what if the collection is rather large?  it seems like in ng-repeat there should be a way to have a running sum on a given object field.

Comment: @Pascamel Check my answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat/25885501#25885501) i think that that one working for what you asking about with filter

Comment: exactly what I was looking for when I landed on that question, thanks for the heads up @RajaShilpa!

Comment: The main issue with this solution is that the total will be recalculated with every digest, because it is a function call.

Comment: @icfantv how is it iterating over the collection twice?

Answer (score 60):

This is also working both the filter and normal list. The first thing to create a new filter for the sum of all values from the list, and also given solution for a sum of the total quantity.
In details code check it [***fiddler link***](https://jsfiddle.net/51ok4mpb/).

```
angular.module("sampleApp", [])
        .filter('sumOfValue', function () {
        return function (data, key) {        
            if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
                return 0;        
            var sum = 0;        
            angular.forEach(data,function(value){
                sum = sum + parseInt(value[key], 10);
            });        
            return sum;
        }
    }).filter('totalSumPriceQty', function () {
        return function (data, key1, key2) {        
            if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key1)  || angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
                return 0;        
            var sum = 0;
            angular.forEach(data,function(value){
                sum = sum + (parseInt(value[key1], 10) * parseInt(value[key2], 10));
            });
            return sum;
        }
    }).controller("sampleController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
          {"id": 1,"details": "test11","quantity": 2,"price": 100}, 
          {"id": 2,"details": "test12","quantity": 5,"price": 120}, 
          {"id": 3,"details": "test3","quantity": 6,"price": 170}, 
          {"id": 4,"details": "test4","quantity": 8,"price": 70}
        ];
    });


<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xsml-12">
      <label>Search</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilter" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xsml-12">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2">
        <h4>Id</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xsml-4">
        <h4>Details</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2 text-right">
        <h4>Quantity</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2 text-right">
        <h4>Price</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2 text-right">
        <h4>Total</h4>

      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="item in resultValue=(items | filter:{'details':searchFilter})">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2">{{item.id}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xsml-4">{{item.details}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2 text-right">{{item.quantity}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2 text-right">{{item.price}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2 text-right">{{item.quantity * item.price}}</div>
      </div>
      <div colspan='3' class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xsml-8 text-right">
        <h4>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'quantity'}}</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2 text-right">
        <h4>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'price'}}</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xsml-2 text-right">
        <h4>{{resultValue | totalSumPriceQty:'quantity':'price'}}</h4>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

check this [***Fiddle Link***](https://jsfiddle.net/51ok4mpb/)

Comment: Hey I am getting `'undefined'` when using the `resultValue`, but if i use `items` it works fine, any ideas..??

Comment: Where first you check the following code "resultValue=(items | filter:{'details':searchFilter})", because all filter values store in that variable "resultValue". i think you mistaken for that {} or () this, verify once again.

Comment: If i use `items` it will not work with filters, help!

Comment: my code is like this 
`ng-repeat="campaign in filteredCampaigns=(campaigns | filter:{'name':q})"` and `{{ filteredCampaigns | campaignTotal: 'totalCommission'  | number: 2 }}`

Comment: yes, because items is not yet filtered, after the filter is happened that result is must to store to any other model and should use that model only. In my sample i used "resultValue" model.

Comment: ng-repeat="campaign in filteredCampaigns=(campaigns | filter:{'name':q})" this one is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77882/discussion-between-rajashilpa-and-salal-aslam).

Comment: Hey @RajaShilpa just came across this thread and the code works great for me besides one thing, when using the `sum = sum + data[i...` it would just give me a long string of the numbers added together like: `0152245` instead of the desired result `82`. So i did some tweaking and when applying the `-` operator instead of the `+` it would give me the result of `-82` for now I applied a filter to turn that negative positive. Why would this be happening ?

Comment: @Kepoly, I don't know what scenario that happened, can you share the sample code yours?, it help to find a problem. I will check and refactor it and sent you back. :-). Thanks for your contribution, Thanks advance. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle but i think you should change to '||' operator instead of '&&' at lines #5 and #16

Comment: This have same problem... for each digest it calculate over list again... for small lists its ok...

Answer (score 41):

Realizing this answered long ago, but wanted to post different approach not presented...

Use `ng-init` to tally your total. This way, you do not have to iterate in the HTML and iterate in the controller.  In this scenario, I think this is a cleaner/simpler solution. (If the tallying logic was more complex, I definitely would recommend moving the logic to the controller or service as appropriate.)

```
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="product in cart.products">
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
        <td ng-init="itemTotal = product.price * product.quantity; controller.Total = controller.Total + itemTotal">{{itemTotal}} €</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total :</td>
        <td>{{ controller.Total }}</td> // Here is the total value of my cart
    </tr>
```

Of course, in your controller, simply define/initialize your `Total` field:

```
// random controller snippet
function yourController($scope..., blah) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.Total = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the most angular way. Simple, readable and declarative. So, the logic it represents remains where it belongs.

Comment: This method hides the calculation in the cell presentation, which is easy to understand here, but gets pretty messy with complex tables.

Comment: The other issue with this is that it doesn't have two way binding either.

Answer (score 18):

You can calculate total inside `ng-repeat` follow:

```
<tbody ng-init="total = 0">
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
    <td ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + (product.price * product.quantity)">${{ product.price * product.quantity }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>${{ total }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Check result here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gb8XiCf2RWiozFI3xWzp?p=preview

In case automatic update result: http://plnkr.co/edit/QSxYbgjDjkuSH2s5JBPf?p=preview (Thanks – VicJordan)

Comment: this wont work when the list is filtered - `tbody` is initialized only once, but `tr` each time the list is filtered, resulting in incorrect sum

Comment: Can you make an example on plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: Hmm, yes, it's not work in filter because filter here just show/hide on view, not update `$scope`

Comment: @HuyNguyen, I have edited your above code. Please check here : http://plnkr.co/edit/QSxYbgjDjkuSH2s5JBPf?p=preview  . Here what I want is the if user change the quantity then 4th column (price * quantity) should be updated automatically. Could you please have a look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

### This is my solution

sweet and simple custom filter:

(but only related to simple sum of values, not sum product, I've made up `sumProduct` filter and appended it as edit to this post).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

    .filter('total', function () {
        return function (input, property) {
            var i = input instanceof Array ? input.length : 0;
// if property is not defined, returns length of array
// if array has zero length or if it is not an array, return zero
            if (typeof property === 'undefined' || i === 0) {
                return i;
// test if property is number so it can be counted
            } else if (isNaN(input[0][property])) {
                throw 'filter total can count only numeric values';
// finaly, do the counting and return total
            } else {
                var total = 0;
                while (i--)
                    total += input[i][property];
                return total;
            }
        };
    })
```

## [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tztw6ysn/)

### EDIT: sumProduct

This is `sumProduct` filter, it accepts any number of arguments. As a argument it accepts name of the property from input data, and it can handle nested property (nesting marked by dot: `property.nested`);

- Passing zero argument returns length of input data.
- Passing just one argument returns simple sum of values of that properties.
- Passing more arguments returns sum of products of values of passed properties (scalar sum of properties).

here's JS Fiddle and the code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .filter('sumProduct', function() {
        return function (input) {
            var i = input instanceof Array ? input.length : 0;
            var a = arguments.length;
            if (a === 1 || i === 0)
                return i;

            var keys = [];
            while (a-- > 1) {
                var key = arguments[a].split('.');
                var property = getNestedPropertyByKey(input[0], key);
                if (isNaN(property))
                    throw 'filter sumProduct can count only numeric values';
                keys.push(key);
            }

            var total = 0;
            while (i--) {
                var product = 1;
                for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++)
                    product *= getNestedPropertyByKey(input[i], keys[k]);
                total += product;
            }
            return total;

            function getNestedPropertyByKey(data, key) {
                for (var j = 0; j < key.length; j++)
                    data = data[key[j]];
                return data;
            }
        }
    })
```

## [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwd1xjk6/10/)

Answer (score 4):

**Simple Solution**

Here is a simple solution. No additional for loop required.

***HTML part***

```
         <table ng-init="ResetTotalAmt()">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="product in cart.products">
                    <td ng-init="CalculateSum(product)">{{product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.price * product.quantity}} €</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Total :</td>
                    <td>{{cart.TotalAmt}}</td> // Here is the total value of my cart
                </tr>

           </table>
```

**Script Part**

```
 $scope.cart.TotalAmt = 0;
 $scope.CalculateSum= function (product) {
   $scope.cart.TotalAmt += (product.price * product.quantity);
 }
//It is enough to Write code $scope.cart.TotalAmt =0; in the function where the cart.products get allocated value. 
$scope.ResetTotalAmt = function (product) {
   $scope.cart.TotalAmt =0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple way to do this with ng-repeat and ng-init to aggregate all the values and extend the model with a item.total property.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="setTotals(item)">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.unitCost | number:2}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.total | number:2}}</td>
</tr>
<tr class="bg-warning">
                    <td>Totals</td>
                    <td>{{invoiceCount}}</td>
                    <td></td>                    
                    <td>{{invoiceTotal | number:2}}</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

The ngInit directive calls the set total function for each item. 
The setTotals function in the controller calculates each item total. It also uses the invoiceCount and invoiceTotal scope variables to aggregate (sum) the quantity and total for all items.

```
$scope.setTotals = function(item){
        if (item){
            item.total = item.quantity * item.unitCost;
            $scope.invoiceCount += item.quantity;
            $scope.invoiceTotal += item.total;
        }
    }
```

for more information and demo look at this link:

http://www.ozkary.com/2015/06/angularjs-calculate-totals-using.html

Comment: Links to your blog post that might go link dead are discouraged on StackOverlow.  Also, when I look at the page I get a 502 Bad Gateway error in the middle of your page.  Answer the question right here not a link to somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of solving this, extending from Vaclav's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26993269/1836776) to solve this particular calculation — i.e. a calculation on each row.

```
    .filter('total', function () {
        return function (input, property) {
            var i = input instanceof Array ? input.length : 0;
            if (typeof property === 'undefined' || i === 0) {
                return i;
            } else if (typeof property === 'function') {
                var total = 0; 
                while (i--)
                    total += property(input[i]);
                return total;
            } else if (isNaN(input[0][property])) {
                throw 'filter total can count only numeric values';
            } else {
                var total = 0;
                while (i--)
                    total += input[i][property];
                return total;
            }
        };
    })
```

To do this with a calculation, just add a calculation function to your scope, e.g.

```
$scope.calcItemTotal = function(v) { return v.price*v.quantity; };
```

You would use `{{ datas|total:calcItemTotal|currency }}` in your HTML code. This has the advantage of not being called for every digest, because it uses filters, and can be used for simple or complex totals.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg7m0xde/)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer elegant solutions

**In Template**

```
<td>Total: {{ totalSum }}</td>
```

**In Controller**

```
$scope.totalSum = Object.keys(cart.products).map(function(k){
    return +cart.products[k].price;
}).reduce(function(a,b){ return a + b },0);
```

*If you're using ES2015 (aka ES6)*

```
$scope.totalSum = Object.keys(cart.products)
  .map(k => +cart.products[k].price)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom Angular filter that takes the dataset object array and the key in each object to sum. The filter can then return the sum:

```
.filter('sumColumn', function(){
        return function(dataSet, columnToSum){
            let sum = 0;

            for(let i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++){
                sum += parseFloat(dataSet[i][columnToSum]) || 0;
            }

            return sum;
        };
    })
```

Then in your table to sum a column you can use:

```
<th>{{ dataSet | sumColumn: 'keyInObjectToSum' }}</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution to this problem:

```
<td>Total: {{ calculateTotal() }}</td>
```

script

```
$scope.calculateVAT = function () {
    return $scope.cart.products.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + (currentValue.price * currentValue.quantity), 0);
};
```

reduce will execute for each product in products array.
Accumulator is the total accumulated amount, currentValue is the current element of the array and the 0 in the last is the initial value

Answer (score 1):

You may try using services of angular js, it has worked for me..giving the code snippets below

Controller code:

```
$scope.total = 0;
var aCart = new CartService();

$scope.addItemToCart = function (product) {
    aCart.addCartTotal(product.Price);
};

$scope.showCart = function () {    
    $scope.total = aCart.getCartTotal();
};
```

Service Code:

```
app.service("CartService", function () {

    Total = [];
    Total.length = 0;

    return function () {

        this.addCartTotal = function (inTotal) {
            Total.push( inTotal);
        }

        this.getCartTotal = function () {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < Total.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(Total[i], 10); 
            }
            return sum;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4]" ng-init="mc.sum = ($first ? 0 : mc.sum) + n">{{n}}</li>
      <li>sum : {{mc.sum}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It require you to add name to controller as `Controller as SomeName` so we can cache variable in there (is it really require? I don't familiar with using $parent so I don't know)

Then for each repeat, add `ng-init"SomeName.SumVariable = ($first ? 0 : SomeName.SumVariable) + repeatValue"`

`$first` for checking it is first then it reset to zero, else it would continue aggregate value

http://jsfiddle.net/thainayu/harcv74f/

Answer (score 0):

I expanded a bit on RajaShilpa's answer.  You can use syntax like:

```
{{object | sumOfTwoValues:'quantity':'products.productWeight'}}
```

so that you can access an object's child object.  Here is the code for the filter:

```
.filter('sumOfTwoValues', function () {
    return function (data, key1, key2) {
        if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key1) === 'undefined' || typeof (key2) === 'undefined') {
            return 0;
        }
        var keyObjects1 = key1.split('.');
        var keyObjects2 = key2.split('.');
        var sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var value1 = data[i];
            var value2 = data[i];
            for (j = 0; j < keyObjects1.length; j++) {
                value1 = value1[keyObjects1[j]];
            }
            for (k = 0; k < keyObjects2.length; k++) {
                value2 = value2[keyObjects2[k]];
            }
            sum = sum + (value1 * value2);
        }
        return sum;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking Vaclav's answer and making it more Angular-like:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('total', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return function (input, property) {
        var i = input instanceof Array ? input.length : 0,
            p = $parse(property);

        if (typeof property === 'undefined' || i === 0) {
            return i;
        } else if (isNaN(p(input[0]))) {
            throw 'filter total can count only numeric values';
        } else {
            var total = 0;
            while (i--)
                total += p(input[i]);
            return total;
        }
    };
}]);
```

This gives you the benefit of even accessing nested and array data:

```
{{data | total:'values[0].value'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In html

```
<b class="text-primary">Total Amount: ${{ data.allTicketsTotalPrice() }}</b>
```

in javascript

```
  app.controller('myController', function ($http) {
            var vm = this;          
            vm.allTicketsTotalPrice = function () {
                var totalPrice = 0;
                angular.forEach(vm.ticketTotalPrice, function (value, key) {
                    totalPrice += parseFloat(value);
                });
                return totalPrice.toFixed(2);
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Huy Nguyen's answer is almost there. To make it work, add:

```
ng-repeat="_ in [ products ]"
```

...to the line with ng-init. The list always has a single item, so Angular will repeat the block exactly once.

Zybnek's demo using filtering can be made to work by adding:

```
ng-repeat="_ in [ [ products, search ] ]"
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/dLSntiy8EyahZ0upDpgy?p=preview.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Angular 6: Grand Total**       
 **<h2 align="center">Usage Details Of {{profile$.firstName}}</h2>
        <table align ="center">
          <tr>
            <th>Call Usage</th>
            <th>Data Usage</th>
            <th>SMS Usage</th>
            <th>Total Bill</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of bills$">
            <td>{{ user.callUsage}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.dataUsage }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.smsUsage }}</td>
       <td>{{user.callUsage *2 + user.dataUsage *1 + user.smsUsage *1}}</td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>Grand Total</th>
            <th></th>
            <td>{{total( bills$)}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>**


    **Controller:**
        total(bills) {
            var total = 0;
            bills.forEach(element => {
total = total + (element.callUsage * 2 + element.dataUsage * 1 + element.smsUsage * 1);
            });
            return total;
        }
```

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*I usually use this simple code that below.*
*Make sure vm.myArray list not be 'null' in calculating.*

```
vm.totalQuantity = 0;
$.each(vm.myArray, function (i, v) {
     vm.totalQuantity += v.Quantity;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

After reading all the answers here - how to summarize grouped information, i decided to skip it all and just loaded one of the SQL javascript libraries. I'm using alasql, yeah it takes a few secs longer on load time but saves countless time in coding and debugging, Now to group and sum() I just use,

```
$scope.bySchool = alasql('SELECT School, SUM(Cost) AS Cost from ? GROUP BY School',[restResults]);
```

I know this sounds like a bit of a rant on angular/js but really SQL solved this 30+ years ago and we shouldn't have to re-invent it within a browser.

Comment: This is just pretty awful.  Just wow  SMH  - I will let other people down vote.  My mouth is wide open with this answer.....