# ng-repeat - count within html loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there anyway to count an item, then display it outside of the loop?

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in values">
   <td>value.total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Total Of All Values: {{ total }}</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried using `ng-init()` to no success as I think it's over-riding each time.

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in values">
   <td ng-init="total = total + value.total>value.total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Total Of All Values: {{ total }}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there anyway of doing it here, without making a function in my controller?

Comment: Well, it is possible and the answers show how, but do you believe such calculations should be done in the template?

Comment: Thanks for the question..I was wondering how this can be achieved..

Comment: @Alias http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat/25885501#25885501 - check this post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`total` which is initialized in ng-repeat will be of a different scope and can not be accessed outside the loop.

Try this:

```
<table ng-init="total = 0">
<tr ng-repeat="value in values">
   <td ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + value.total">{{value.total}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Total Of All Values: {{ total }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of $parent notation to access a $scope variable (from outside ng-repeat) in the ng-repeat scope. So now after initializing it will calculate the total and store it in the $scope variable which was initialized outside.

Code:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="test">
    <table ng-init="total=0;">
        <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
            <td ng-init="$parent.total = total + value">{{value}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Of All Values: {{ total }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjwLjcuk/)

Answer (score 1):

Although they do seem to be similar `ngRepeat` does not work like a `for` loop in an imperative programming language. The `ngRepeat` directive consists of two steps that run seperately. First, it produces an array / a map with the repeatet values. Secondly, it renders the template (the elements inside the element with `ngRepeat`) for each repeatet value. It does not however iterate over a code block like an imperative programming language.

Even though you may achieve what you try to do with `$parent.total`, you may run into other pitfalls with this solution as soon as the contents of your array change. To cut it short, you should rather find another way to sum up the values in the array.

In my opinion, the best place to sum up the values is the controller with a line like this:

```
$scope.total = values.reduce(function (a,b) {return a+b});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this in your JS function.

```
        $scope.values = data;
        angular.forEach($scope.values,function(value){
          $scope.total += value.value;
        });
```

Working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5WZ9alCXzq115wi3xl4B?p=preview