# How to count some using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Im adding Columns into using using Mvc Angular when the colum is added into table it should be count the value Like

```
ID    Price      Qty   Amount
1      10         1     10
2      20         2      40
---------------------------------
Total Items--->3    Amount--->50
--------------------------------------
```

Please Suggest me Im New for angular & mvc

Comment: put some code in fiddle

Comment: Do you store these values in array? how do you add them? please, post some code

Comment: This [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22731145/492258) is nice point to start for you

Comment: MVC is not related to it.
plus, you can always do a function when you create a new row, that has a for loop that sums and saves the Qty, and amount with a simple $scope and ng-model

Comment: Im totally confused how to write code plz Helpme

Comment: @afridishayed Could u please look into this article ? It might help u.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667130/ng-repeat-count-within-html-loop/25667437#25667437

Comment: thanks its Helpming me