# Calculate the sum of values for each ng-model in array angularjs

Tags: angularjs

`{
    "specific":
    {
        "first":{
            "title":"222",
            "items":[
                {
                    "z": "1",
                    "s":"2",
                    "p":"3",
                },
                {
                    "z": "12",
                    "s":"12",
                    "p":"12"

                }
            ],
               "results":{
                    "z": "13",
                    "s":"14",
                    "p":"15"
                }
        }
    }
}`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(item, q)  in first.items">
  <input ng-model="q.z">
  <input ng-model="q.s">
  <input ng-model="q.p">
```

Results should calculate the values for repeated elements in items (for example, `item1.z + item2.z = results.z`).

How can I calculate the values for each repeated element for item in items with angularJS?

Comment: It might help you!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to like this.

In Template

```
<td>Total: {{ getTotal() }}</td>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cart.products.length; i++){
        var product = $scope.cart.products[i];
        total += (product.price * product.quantity);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: `$scope.getTotal = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.first.items.length; i++){
            var item = $scope.first.items[i];
            total += item.z;
        }
        return total;
    } `     as a result it returns 112  (item1 z, item2 z), the same result if use `<div  ng-init="items.total.z = items.total.z + q.z"></div>`   What i'm missing?

Comment: try to this. 
<div ng-init="items.total.z = (items.total.z) + (q.z)"></div>

Comment: fixed with  ` total = total + parseInt(item.z);`   Thanks for your help!