# Angular JS, Shopping List, Total wont work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items with a total button, but for some reason the total button does not work. My professor said we could put two functions in a controller.

**Html**:

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <h3> Grocery List </h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model"groceryList">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p ng-repeat="grocery in groceries">
            {{grocery.name| uppercase}}:  
            {{grocery.price}}
        </p>
        <button onclick="calcTotal()">Total</button>  
        <p ng-repeat="grocery.price in groceries">
            Total: {{ getTotal() }}
        </p>
    </div> 
</body>
```

**Js**:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('myController', function groceryList($scope){

        $scope.groceries=[ 
            {name:'apples', price: 5},
            {name: 'oranges', price: 4},
            {name:'pears', price: 3}
        ];

        $scope.calcTotal= function() {
            var total = 0;

            for (i=0; i<grocery.length; i++){
                total+= grocery[i].price;
            }

            return total;
        }

});
```

Comment: Check your code. You are not closing your div tag and it defines de controller ln that block.

Comment: Your return statement should be outside of the for() loop. The way the code is written right now, it returns the total as the first grocery item's price and then stops.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like typing error please check out {{ getTotal() }} to {{calTotal}}

Answer (score 0):

I found some error on the console and the logic but anyway I'm a noob too. The getTotal() function doesn't seems to be useful.
If you want to work with the $scope just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat), in my opinion it's better to delete or push the items in the array as new objects and then operate on them. I use $scope for binding of data between model and view. Just for this.

This works:

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
<h3> Grocery List </h3>
<input type="text" ng-model"groceryList">

<div ng-controller="myController">
    <p ng-repeat="grocery in groceries"> {{grocery.name| uppercase}}:  
     {{grocery.price}} </p> 
 <button ng-click="calcTotal()">Total</button>
 <p> {{total}}</p>
 <p ng-repeat="grocery.price in groceries">Total: {{ getTotal() }}</p>
 </body>
```

**JS**

```
var shopApp = angular.module('myModule', []);  //declare module

shopApp.controller('myController', function groceryList($scope) {
    var grocery = [
    { name: 'apples', price: 5 },
    { name: 'oranges', price: 4 },
    { name: 'pears', price: 3 } ];
    $scope.groceries = grocery;

    $scope.calcTotal = function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < grocery.length; i++) {

            total += grocery[i].price;
            console.log(total);
        };
        $scope.total = total;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the ng-repeat in the p element holding the total value. This will run the function getTotal() (which doesn't exist in the code above do you mean to use ) for each object in the array (in this case 3 times).

You also need to specify the scope within the javascript.

```
$scope.calcTotal= function() {
var total = 0;
for (i=0; i< $scope.groceries.length; i++){

total+= $scope.groceries[i].price;
}
return total;
}
```

You may wish to create a new scope object called $scope.getTotal and use that instead of returning a value.

```
$scope.getTotal+= $scope.groceries[i].price;
```

Just make sure you clear the value first.