# How to use cummulative sum in angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to find cumulative sum in angular js ng-repeat

```
<table ng-init='cummSum =0'>
    <tr ng-repeat='obj in objArr'>
        <td>{{x = obj.val}}</td><td>{{y = x + obj.val}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat) will be interesting for you I think.

Comment: Can't we do it in ng-repeat only without iterating in javascript

Comment: I guess in some sort of way, but why would you want to do that? Your code becomes messy like this. It's good practice to keep code and UI as separated as possible.

Comment: If possible please send me in html way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GzYSGij3thd3FVaiIWTc?p=preview)

```
  <table ng-init="objArr[0].cumul = objArr[0].val">
      <tr ng-repeat='obj in objArr'>
          <td>{{x = obj.val}}</td><td ng-init="obj.cumul = objArr[$index-1].cumul + obj.val">{{obj.cumul}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Note that as @JensBrulmans said, it is not a good practice to do this kind of logic into the HTML. Also my solution isn't really clean in my own opinion till you can't lock as much things in HTML than you could in JS.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you @Okazari. Just i wanna know is it possible in to find the sum of records without using script. & this is helped me