# How to use Angular Filters on Frontend/Templates

Tags: angularjs, templates, filter

I have a list of numbers repeated horizontally using ng-repeat. At the end of the  last number, there is a div where I wish to display the sum of all numbers. How can I do it using filter on screen. Is this possible at all.

I know the way of binding it by a variable in JS. But I want to achieve it in template itself. something like:

Total{{sum(n in repeatedarray)}}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with multiple ways. Please follow below links for quick reference.

[Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

You can create a custom filter for this as specified below.

```
angular.module('caco.feed.filter', [])
.filter('sumByKey', function() {
    return function(data, key) {
        if (typeof(data) === 'undefined' || typeof(key) === 'undefined') {
            return 0;
        }

        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sum += parseInt(data[i][key]);
        }

        return sum;
    };
});
```

For your reference please follow below working example for same.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meWeWr)

Comment: Never used a custom filter before...What is data and key and how are they passed

Comment: works fine...only I will be adding a check of data!=== null, since my array can be null and typeof(null) returns object.