# How to get the Total value in column in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. How to get the total amount in the table Total Amount column and display in input textbox? I think this plunker can solve my problem but I can't access it now. http://plnkr.co/edit/CHBm8RCqW5RNZWrzAe5r?p=preview

Here is my table sample

[image]

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Total Amount</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="payment_queue in data | filter:searchFilter">

                        <td>{{payment_queue.product_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{payment_queue.sold_quantity}}</td>
                        <td>{{payment_queue.amount}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

Total Amount: <input type="text value=""> <--- the total amount value goes here...
```

js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']); 
    myApp.controller('productsalesController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {



                    $scope.data=[];

                    $http.get("../php/paymentQueuedata.php")
                        .success(function(data){
                            $scope.data = data;
                        })
                        .error(function() {
                            $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
                        });

         }]);
```

php json

```
    <?php
    //database settings
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "rmsdb");

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from payment_queue");


$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
    print json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: You need to calculate it in your controller and assign it to a `$scope` variable. Then you can use something like `<input ng-model="columnTotal">`. Angular is not THAT cheap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Comment: Please share your sample json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to my problem..

in my controller

```
$scope.totalAmount = function(){
            var total = 0;
            for(count=0;count<$scope.data.length;count++){
                total += parseInt($scope.data[count].total_amount,10);
            }
            return total;
        };
```

in html

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Total Amount</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="payment_queue in data | filter:searchFilter">

                        <td>{{payment_queue.product_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{payment_queue.sold_quantity}}</td>
                        <td>{{payment_queue.amount}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

Total Amount: <input type="text value="{{ totalAmount() }}"> <--- the total amount value goes here...
```

Comment: total_amount. Can you explain about this variable

Answer (score 5):

There a way to get the totals without using a function.

Just use ng-init. If you need to allow the list to change or be filtered, use ng-repeat with it to force recalculation of the totals.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Ext</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="_ in [ [ search, products ] ]" ng-init="total = 0">
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter: search">
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
      <td ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + (product.price * product.quantity)">${{ product.price * product.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total</b></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><b>${{ total }}</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/dLSntiy8EyahZ0upDpgy?p=preview for a workinig example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. This is good solution for your problem.

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.years}}</td>
                <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
                <td>{{item.interest}}%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>{{getTotal('years')}}</td>
                <td>{{getTotal('amount')}}</td>
                <td>{{getTotal('interest')}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.items = [
    {name: 'xxx', amount: 13, years: 3, interest: 2},    
    {name: 'yyy', amount: 23, years: 4, interest: 3},
    {name: 'zzz', amount: 123, years: 4, interest: 4}
];

$scope.getTotal = function(int) {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(el) {
        total += el[int];
    });
    return total;
};
});
```

you can use this url also. Thank you !!!
http://plnkr.co/edit/CHBm8RCqW5RNZWrzAe5r?p=preview