# AngularJS Sum of an Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array in AngularJS, which I'm getting from a WCF Service.
I can achieve the sum of the array using a function like below.
reference: [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cart.products.length; i++){
        var product = $scope.cart.products[i];
        total += (product.price);
    }
    return total;
}
```

But, is there any way to achieve this without filter? just like $scope.cart.products.price.Sum()? 
I already used so many filters and functions in my code, want to reduce its count.

Answer (score 10):

Use `reduce`.

```
$scope.cart.products.reduce(function(acc,current){
    return acc + current.price;
},0);
```

Or in ES6:

```
$scope.cart.products.reduce((acc,current) => acc + current.price, 0);
```

Check [here for MDN docs on reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Or $scope.cart.products.reduce(function(sum,current){
    return sum + current.price;
}, 0);

Comment: The acc (or previous value) is the value previously returned in the last invocation of the callback, or initialValue, if supplied. On the second loop it will be number without price property