# Angularjs ng-repeat sum the fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I am new to angularjs I have a problem in calculation the sum of the field my code is like this

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,item) in expenses_data | groupBy: 'category_name'">

  <h4 ng-cloak><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> {{ key }}</h4>

  <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="expn_head in item">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{ expn_head.name }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="expenses.expenditure_head[expn_head.id]">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

How do I sum up all the `expenses.expenditure_head` value entered and put it in the new text field. Is there any function like this:

```
<input type=text ng-value="{{ sum() }}">
```

and js

```
$scope.sum = function() {

  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.expenses.expenditure_head; i++) {
    var myValue = $expenses.expenditure_head[i];
    total += myValue;
  }
  return total;
}
```

**json**

```
    [
{
"id":23,
"name":"Agency Commission",
"expenditure_category_id":1,
"category_name":"Main"
},
{
"id":22,
"name":"Bonus to Local Staff",
"expenditure_category_id":1,
"category_name":"Main"
},
{
"id":48,
"name":"Advance for Expenses",
"expenditure_category_id":2,
"category_name":"Other Dept's Budget Exp"
},
{
"id":49,
"name":"Agency TDS",
"expenditure_category_id":2,
"category_name":"Other Dept's Budget Exp"
}
```

]

Can anyone show me the right direction? I have trying this for a day.

Comment: check this, it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to do so inside the controller. Create a function call it getSum()

```
    $scope.getSum = function(){
      var total = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.someVar; i++){
        var myValue = $someVar[i];
        sum += myValue;
      }
      return sum;
    };
```

Then inside your code you do something like

```
 <td>Total: {{ getSum() }}</td>
```

Comment: can you please provide me html also

Comment: <td>Total: {{ getSum() }}</td>
 goes inside your template