# summing up in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am trying to get the sum of the ngRepeat i have here and i want to do it in the html file is there anyway i can store the sum as it increments

```
 <div class = "row" ng-repeat= "product in products">
   <div class = "col"><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="{{product.product_id}}"></div>
   <div class = "col">{{product.product_name}}</div>
   <div class = "col"><input type="text" ng-model="quantity"></div>
   <div class = "col">{{product.price * quantity}}</div>
</div>

   <div class = "row" align="center">
      <div class="col">
         <strong>Total : {{total}}</strong>
      </div>
```

Comment: DO you want to sum of what?  can you please edit your question and give more clarity ? YOu want to todal of ngRepeast means do you want totals of how many products or you want total of cost {product price* quantity} for all prioducts?

Comment: Exactly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat (with answer)

Comment: quantity should be product specific. replace ng-model=" quantity" with ng-model="product.quantity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-init for this like

```
<div ng-init="items.total = {}">
    <div class = "row" ng-repeat= "product in products" >
           <div class = "col"><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="{{product.product_id}}"></div>
           <div class = "col">{{product.product_name}}</div>
           <div class = "col"><input type="text" ng-model="quantity"></div>
           <div class = "col" ng-init="items.total.quantity= items.total.quantity + product.price * quantity">{{product.price * quantity}}</div>
        </div>

           <div class = "row" align="center">
              <div class="col">
                 <strong>Total : {{items.total.quantity}}</strong>
              </div>
           </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: maybe the init should be outside of the ng-repeat

Comment: can i do it in my app.js so i can calculate all the total amount

Comment: Yes, the calculation should be in js...but for that you have to loop it again in js

Comment: i will try and iterate and do the calculations in the app.js so i can convert the price to a number

Answer (score 0):

i don't know your variables but i assume you  miss

```
{{product.price * product.quantity}}
```

if not please show us error msg ?

Comment: its showing NaN i think its better i do it app.js so i can be able to convert it to a number

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to have your logic in html. But if you want you can try this

```
<div ng-init="temp={total:0}">
     <div class = "row" ng-repeat= "product in products" ng-init="total=0">
       <div class = "col" ng-init="temp.total=temp.total+product.price"><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="{{product.product_id}}"></div>
       <div class = "col">{{product.product_name}}</div>
       <div class = "col"><input type="text" ng-model="quantity"></div>
       <div class = "col">{{product.price * quantity}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

       <div class = "row" align="center">
          <div class="col">
             <strong>Total : {{temp.total}}</strong>
          </div>
```

Comment: i think i will follow your advice i will do it in app.js