# sum of values in a list using angular way

Tags: angularjs

I have a short piece of [sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/djovoLsx/2/) where myself trying to get total of values in angular way as,

```
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="total = 0">
  <ul>
      <li  ng-repeat="x in myarr" >  {{x.val}} 
     <span ng-if="$last">, Total - {{total = total+x.val}}</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But total is incorrect. How can it be achieved?

**EDIT**: Myself trying to get total within the `ng-repeat` loop beside last element. There is an accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145) and below answer also work in same logic. But In that method, the function `getTotal()` will call `myarr.length` times and each time the array loops in controller right? So as per example in the question, array will loop completely 6 times (`myarr.length` + once in `ng-repeat` ie, 5+1). Do i wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Comment: Myself trying to get total within  the `ng-repeat` loop beside last element.

Comment: @mpsbhat , Added one more method in answer , working only in ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method, no function used in controller , using `ng-init` in `ng-repeat`

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.myarr = [{id: 1, val: 500},{id: 2,val: 300},{id: 3,val: 200},{id: 4,val: 600},{id: 5,val: 100}];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="total=0">
  <ul >
      <li ng-repeat="x in myarr" ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + (x.val)"> {{x.val}} 
      <span ng-if="$last">{{total}}</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Another method ,

Use `array.reduce` to add sum of array [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.myarr = [{id: 1, val: 500},{id: 2,val: 300},{id: 3,val: 200},{id: 4,val: 600},{id: 5,val: 100}];
$scope.addTotal = function(){
var sum = $scope.myarr.reduce($scope.add);
return sum.val;
}
$scope.add = function(a,b){
 return {val:a.val + b.val};
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="total=0">
  <ul >
      <li ng-repeat="x in myarr" >  {{x.val}} 
      <span ng-if="$last">{{addTotal()}}</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Method #1 Awesome..! Kudos angularjs `$parent`

Comment: Accept the answer pls

Answer (score 1):

Try doing all calculations in angular controller itself and storing it in varaible. But if you are worried about values in array constantly changing you can also use a calcTotal function in your controller. Also `ng-repeat` should be on `li` and not `ul`.

```
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="total = 0">
  <ul >
      <li ng-repeat="x in myarr">  {{x.val}} 
     <span ng-if="$last">, Total - {{getTotal()}} or {{totalValue}}</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Your controller will be like

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.myarr = [{id: 1, val: 500},{id: 2,val: 300},{id: 3,val: 200},{id: 4,val: 600},{id: 5,val: 100}];
 //first approach
 $scope.totalValue = 0;
 for(i=0;i<$scope.myarr.length;i++){
 if($scope.myarr[i] && $scope.myarr[i].val)
    $scope.totalValue+=$scope.myarr[i].val;
 }

 //OR

 //second approach
 $scope.getTotal = function(){
 var total = 0;
 for(i=0;i<$scope.myarr.length;i++){
 if($scope.myarr[i] && $scope.myarr[i].val)
    total+=$scope.myarr[i].val;
 }
 return total;
 }
});
```

If you are using variable approach, you will have to explicitly calculate **$scope.getTotal** everytime the array values change. By the function approach it will happen itself, but binding functions on UI is little expensive as they keep re-calculating on every digest cycle.

Comment: FYI, I should get the total `1700` in the given sample and the array generated dynamically.

Comment: I had not added actual javascript functions in controller. Check again now.

Comment: Its fine.. I like to know is there any angular way without looping the full array again in controller.  That is, summing within ng-repeat loop only.

Comment: In this method, the function `getTotal()` will call `myarr.length` times and each time the array loops in controller right? So in the given example in the question, array will loop completely `5+1=6 times`. Do i wrong?

Comment: No. It will get called only when ng-if is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `angular.forEach` to loop and have you total count.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.total = 0;
 $scope.myarr = [{id: 1, val: 500},{id: 2,val: 300},{id: 3,val: 200},{id: 4,val: 600},{id: 5,val: 100}];
  angular.forEach($scope.myarr, function(value){$scope.total+=value.val});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul >
      <li ng-repeat="x in myarr" >  {{x.val}} 
      <span ng-if="$last">{{total}}</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```