# Sum of Dynamic fields in Anglurjs

Tags: angularjs, dynamicform

Hi I have a dynamic fields like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in staff_categories">
   <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="category.permanent"></td>
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="category.temp"></td>
</tr>
```

It is working fine as expected. It iterate according to staff_categories. **Now I want the grand total of category.permanent and category.temp value entered by user and put it in the textbox.** Please help

```
Total permanent:<input type="text">
Total Temp:<input type="text">
```

Comment: You need to create a filter to get the total.
This may helps you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function in the controller that will be called and update a scope variable containing total of these values.

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in staff_categories">
   <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="category.permanent" ng-change="updatePermanentTotal()"></td>
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="category.temp" ng-change="updateTemp()"></td>
</tr>
```

Controller Code

```
$scope.permanentTotal = 0.0;
$scope.tempTotal = 0.0;

$scope.updatePermanentTotal = function(){
  $scope.permanentTotal = 0.0;

  angular.forEach($scope.staff_categories, function(value, key){
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(value.temp)){
       $scope.tempTotal = $scope.tempTotal + parseInt(value.temp);
      }
    })
}

$scope.updateTemp = function(){
      $scope.tempTotal = 0.0;

      angular.forEach($scope.staff_categories, function(value, key){
        $scope.tempTotal = $scope.tempTotal + parseInt(value.temp);
       })
    }
```

And bind those two total variables to two inputs like this.

```
Total permanent:<input type="text" ng-model="permanentTotal">
Total Temp:<input type="text" ng-model="tempTotal">
```

Comment: It is giving NaN value

Comment: I have edited the answer. There was a mistake in angular.forEach function parameters. Had to pass variables named value and key

Comment: Still giving NaN however value.permanent is giving a correct value

Comment: Can u edit your question to include controller code as well ? I can compare my answer with your code then.

Comment: Thanks It worked I just add if(!isNaN(parseInt(value.permanent))){$scope.permanentTotal = $scope.permanentTotal + parseInt(value.permanent);}

Comment: I have edited my answer to include your check. Please mark it as accepted so others can benefit

Comment: and also you have to change angular.forEach(staff_categories, function(value, key) to angular.forEach($scope.staff_categories, function(value, key)

Comment: That is why I asked you to share your code. Its easy that way. No worries

Answer (score 0):

You can use one function and pass parameter to it.

To Display total

```
<p> Permanent Total: {{ getTotal(permanent) }}</p>
<p> Temp Total: {{ getTotal(temp) }}</p>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.getTotal = function(category){
   var total = 0;
   if(category == 'permanent'){
      angular.forEach(staff_categories, function(item){
         total = total + parseInt(item.temp);
      });
   } else {
      angular.forEach(staff_categories, function(item){
         total = total + parseInt(item.permanent);
      });
   }
   return total;
}
```