# Is it possible to calculate and save local variable inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

i have a common block with ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="(position, task) in Tasks.plannedTasks">
     {{(task.plan - (TasksTimeSpent[task.id][task.worker]).toFixed(2)}}
</div>
```

And now i need to set background if :

```
{{(task.plan - (TasksTimeSpent[task.id][task.worker]).toFixed(2)}} < 0
```

task.plan and task.worker can be changed and after this need to check if statement and change shown value
Is it possible to save expression result in variable (for example : curDif), display this variable and check variable inside if? I don't want calculate expression twice.
The way to calculate variable in controller is bad because variable is useless for application logic and need only for displaying but for using controller if task changes - i need to recalculate variable and use watcher for Task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for that:

```
<div ng-repeat="(position, task) in Tasks.plannedTasks">
  <ng-init ng-init="curDif = (task.plan - (TasksTimeSpent[task.id][task.worker]).toFixed(2)">
     {{curDif}}
  </ng-init>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use ng-class as well to set the background.

```
<div ng-repeat="(position, task) in Tasks.plannedTasks">

    <div ng-init="curDif = task.plan - (TasksTimeSpent[task.id][task.worker]).toFixed(2)" ng-class="'my-background':curDif < 0">


    </div>

</div>
```

Then style your background using CSS.

Comment: thanks. I already use it =) My problem was to saving local value inside ng-repeat