# Simple sum ng-repeat column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, sum, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page that returns a list from an ng-repeat. All I need to do is add up the numbers that are returned. I know there is a simple solution. However, I cannot find the correct implementation.

Html:

```
<ion-list class="item-borderless">
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="product in productsToFilter">
        <div class="row">
           {{product.shareCount}}
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.productsToFilter
$scope.productsToFilter = [];

firebase.database().ref('products').once('value', function(products) {
    products.forEach(function(product) {
          var product = {
            shareCount: product.val().shareCount
          }
    }
};
```

Returns a list of numbers, and all I'm looking for is the total of all of them regardless of how many records there are.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat

Comment: how does your products array look like?

Comment: Not a duplicate, I don't need to multiply across columns for a total.  I just need a running total of the entire column.

Comment: If i've understood your problem correctly , I guess all you need to do is - inside the `forEach` function, just keep adding the value to a variable declared and defined as 0 outside the loop, binded to the view using `$scope`, and display it. Remove the`ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thats about right!

Comment: @MacD you re trying to read element from `productsToFilter` this array but in your controller where you are `push` the element or assign the value for `productsToFilter`. so first you need to assign the value `productsToFilter` than you can able to get your desired result.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/B9RsQ/43/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already iteration over `products` array via `forEach`, then I think you can just add them to a variable to get the total value of `shareCount`.

```
var totalCount = 0;
products.forEach(function(product) {
      totalCount += product.val().shareCount;
      var product = {
        shareCount: product.val().shareCount
      }
}
```