# Calculate total price in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make this code to get the final number of the sum of all `detalle.price` elements. They are all numbers so I need to sum them and post the final number on `sum()`.

```
<div id="pedidos_table">
  <div id="pedidos_table_item" ng-repeat="detalle in detalles">
    <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">{{detalle.name}}</p>
    <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{detalle.price}}$</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pedidos_table_total">
  <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">TOTAL</p>
  <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{sum()}}$</p>
</div>
```

I've tried doing this:

```
$scope.sum = function(){
var total = 0;
total += detalle.price;
return total
}
```

I know there's something missing, but I don't know what.

Comment: post your json file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking your sum method from a `<p></p>` tag is not a best practice as the digest cycle might trigger it multiple times. You might follow this way to achieve the same. Also playing with angular `$scope` is not suggested for production environment, hence use `this` of the controller instance.

```js
// Code goes here
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('myApp', []);

  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);

  MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MyController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    this.product_details = [{
      name: 'XXX',
      price: 25
    }, {
      name: 'YYY',
      price: 30
    }, {
      name: 'ZZZ',
      price: 67
    }];

    vm.total = 0;
    vm.sum = sum;

    function sum() {
      angular.forEach(vm.product_details, function(key, value) {
        vm.total += key.price
      });
    }
  }
})(angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">

  <div ng-repeat="product in ctrl.product_details">
    <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ product.price }}</p>
  </div>

  <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.sum()">Calculate total</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.total">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Really apreciate your help! I got one more question. When the sum returns 0 because there no elements, how do I avoid the NaN print and replace it with number 0?

Comment: You can try this, <div ng-if="vm.total === undefined"><div ng-init="vm.total = 0"></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can have `angular.forEach` to loop through the array and calculate the total.

```
 $scope.sum = function() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.detalles, function(key, value) {
      total += key.price;
    });
    return total;
  }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.detalles = [{
    name: 'Bush',
    price: 2,
    Total:0
  }, {
    name: 'Obama',
    price: 5,
    Total:0
  }, {
    name: 'Trump',
    price: 3,
    Total:0
  }]; 
  
   $scope.sum = function() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.detalles, function(key, value) {
      total += key.price;
    });
    return total;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
 </head>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div id="pedidos_table">
  <div id="pedidos_table_item" ng-repeat="detalle in detalles">
    <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">{{detalle.name}}</p>
    <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{detalle.price}}$</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pedidos_table_total">
  <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">TOTAL</p>
  <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{sum()}}$</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do without click on button when you call api.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.sum = 0;
      $http.post(url')
                .success(function (response) {
                  $scope.detalles = response;
                  sum($scope.detalles);  //call sum function
                 }).error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                    //error
                 });


 function sum(priceArray) {

    angular.forEach(priceArray, function(key, value) {
      $scope.sum += key.price;
    });
  }
```

});

```
 <div id="pedidos_table">
      <div id="pedidos_table_item" ng-repeat="detalle in detalles">
        <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">{{detalle.name}}</p>
        <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{detalle.price}}$</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pedidos_table_total">
      <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">TOTAL</p>
      <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{sum}}</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach is this,

```
<div id="pedidos_table">
  <div id="pedidos_table_item" ng-repeat="detalle in detalles">
    <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">{{detalle.name}}</p>
    <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{detalle.price}}$</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="pedidos_table_total">
  <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">TOTAL</p>
  <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{sum(detalles);}}$</p>
</div>

// this approach can be use dynamically but the other is for a specific requirement
// in this function will get data from the view directly the parsing objects from the data and by adding all the prices, will give total value
    $scope.sum = function(data){
    var total = 0 ;
    angular.forEach(data,function(value,key){
    total += value.price;
    });
    return total
    }
```

second approach is,

```
<div id="pedidos_table">
      <div id="pedidos_table_item" ng-repeat="detalle in detalles">
        <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">{{detalle.name}}</p>
        <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{detalle.price}}$</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pedidos_table_total">
      <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">TOTAL</p>
      <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{sum();}}$</p>
    </div>

    $scope.sum = function(){
    var total = 0 ;
    angular.forEach($scope.detalles,function(value,key){ // this will get array of elements of parse the objects of it
      total += value.price;
    });
    return total
    }
```