# Angularjs : ng-repeat - how to update total sum of list created using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs and trying to create a very simple page, where I am displaying product, price, quantity, subtotal (price * quantity) and Total sum. I want, if user update quantity then subtotal and total sum should update at real time. I tried but couldn't get it.
Trying like this :

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price * Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-init="total = 0">
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
      <td><input value="{{ product.quantity }}"></td>
      <td ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + (product.price * product.quantity)">${{ product.price * product.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>


      <td><b>Total</b></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><b>${{ total }}</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var i = 0;
  $scope.products = [
    {
      "name": "Product 1",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Product 2",
      "quantity": 6,
      "price": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "Product 3",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 26
    },
    {
      "name": "Product 4",
      "quantity": 10,
      "price": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Product 5",
      "quantity": 11,
      "price": 7
    }
    ];
});
</script>
</body>
```

Here is my whole code till now : http://plnkr.co/edit/QSxYbgjDjkuSH2s5JBPf?p=preview

Thanks in advance!

**Note** : This all stuff I want to do in angular way i.e. only in HTML. This data script will go in .js file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to updated link http://plnkr.co/edit/HOCVZC2p3xfG2apoKJDW?p=preview
You don't have a function to calculate totals. You need to add it and call the function on change of any quantity text box.
You also need to add an change event to all the text boxes for quantity `ng-change="updateTotal()"`

```
$scope.updateTotal = function(){
    $scope.total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.products, function(product){
       $scope.total += product.quantity*product.price;
   });
};
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. It works perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: @VicJordan Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make a function that counts the total every time you change the value

table body Html

```
<tbody ng-init="total = 0">
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
      <td><input ng-change="updateTotal()" ng-model="product.quantity"></td>
      <td>${{ product.price * product.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total</b></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><b>${{ total }}</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

And add a function in JS

```
$scope.updateTotal = function(){
      $scope.total = 0;
    for(product of $scope.products){
       $scope.total += product.quantity * product.price
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a function to get the total,

```
   $scope.getTotal = function() {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++) {
          var product = $scope.products[i];
          total += (product.price * product.quantity);
        }
        return total;
      }
```

call the function when the quantity changes,

```
<td>
 <input ng-model="product.quantity" ng-change="getTotal()">
</td>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MYgPBNtnv0n41kgbHyvM?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks a lot the solution but the answer I accepted it more cleaner and efficient. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: It is the same solution proposed above

Comment: Yes result is same but if you have bit closer look you will find the difference. I don't discourage you but this is true what I am saying. Hope you understand. Thanks