# Grouping and summary in Angular loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My data is formatted like so:

```
[{id: 178, uid: "1", when: "2018-01-17", gingerbread: "75", created_at: "2018-01-..., 
{id: 179, uid: "1", when: "2018-01-17", gingerbread: "32", created_at... }];
```

If I wanted to *ngFor loop through an array of these objects and find the sum of `gingerbread` against the `when` can someone shed light on the best way of doing this please?

Comment: Why would you do this in your template?  Couldn't this logic sit in your controller?

Comment: *"the best way of doing this "* sounds a little bit of primarily opinion based.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Can you show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this in controller or server side. Views are for displaying data, not doing math in it.

Comment: I opted for summarising the data in my Laravel controller before it was received by my Angular frontend's request.

Comment: Yep, the best approach. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like this In the controller:

```
var myArray = [{id: 178, uid: "1", when: "2018-01-17", gingerbread: "75", created_at: "2018-01-..., 
          {id: 179, uid: "1", when: "2018-01-17", gingerbread: "32", created_at... }];
$scope.totals = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   $scope.totals[myarray[i].when] +=  +myarray[i].gingerbread; //use '+' to coerce a number
}
```

And then loop over your `$scope.totals` object in the HTML (you'd also probably need to make your object key/value pairs into an array of objects)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can make use of this approach, where you can specify your "when" condition here in the if loop.
---
var obj = [
    {id: 178, uid: "1", when: "2018-01-17", gingerbread: "75", created_at: "2018-01-01"},
    {id: 179, uid: "1", when: "2018-01-17", gingerbread: "32", created_at: "2018-01-01"},
    {id: 180, uid: "1", when: "2018-02-18", gingerbread: "24", created_at: "2018-02-18"}
];

var sum = 0;

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
 if(obj[i].when === "2018-01-17") {
  sum += parseInt(obj[i].gingerbread);
 } 
}
alert(sum);
```