# AngularJS get data without ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html-table

In the table, I already have data from the backend loaded with `data-ng-repeat`. On a new row, I want to calculate the total or avg of each column. Is it possible to get the same data, without using the `ng-repeat`?

```html
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in tableData">
  <th>{{ data.month }}</th>
  <td data-ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-if="column.visible">
    {{ data[column.field] | formatNumber:2 }}
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Total</th>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why would not like you to make it without ng-repeat?

Comment: Because if I do, I get after every row the total again and again. So: normal row, total row, normal row, etc.

Comment: You can simply use answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat

Comment: In your JavaScript, you already have access to all the data you need to make your calculations. Do your calculations there, assign them to new scoped variables and then bind them on another table row after your repeat is done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)