# Calculation of the sum of repeating elements within a filter using the FILTER function of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a list that shows the total of the records, when filtering a single name it still shows me the total of the records and not the total of the filtered record.    **[TRY HERE](https://codepen.io/roalroga/pen/JQPmWe?editors=1000)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  name:
<input type="text" ng-model="model_filter">
  <hr/>
    <table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in records | filter: model_filter">
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Money | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            <td>{{Total | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.records = [
                {
                    "Name": "Rodrigo",
                    "Money": 10
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Rodrigo",
                    "Money": 25
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Arnodl",
                    "Money": 15
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Carlos",
                    "Money": 5
                }
            ]
            $scope.Total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.records.length; i++) {
                $scope.Total += $scope.records[i].Money;
            }

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

RESULT:

[image]

WITH FILTER:

[image]

**MY PROBLEM**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Comment: @Dementic no, this is another question, that solution and review it

Comment: If you click `Run code snippet`, your code returns exactly what you are asking. side note: you can replace your `for` loop with `$scope.total = $scope.records.reduce((a, b) => a.Money + b.Money, 0)`

Comment: i tried, but it not work [Withless loop](https://codepen.io/roalroga/pen/JQPmWe?editors=1000)

Comment: my bad, `$scope.records.reduce((total, b) => total + b['Money'], 0)`

Comment: if you want to get total **without** the filtered results, you can use `$scope.records.reduce((a, b) => { if ($scope.model_filter && $scope.model_filter === b.Name) return a + b.Money; else return a + b.Money; }, 0);`

Comment: i tried, don't work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="model_filter">
  <hr/>
  <table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in records | filter: model_filter">
      <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.Money | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
      <td>{{Total()}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>TotalFiltered</th>
      <td>{{ TotalFiltered() }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.records = [{
          "Name": "Rodrigo",
          "Money": 10
        },
        {
          "Name": "Rodrigo",
          "Money": 25
        },
        {
          "Name": "Arnodl",
          "Money": 15
        },
        {
          "Name": "Carlos",
          "Money": 5
        }
      ]
      $scope.Total = () => $scope.records.reduce((total, b) => total + b.Money, 0);
      $scope.TotalFiltered = () => {
        return $scope.records.reduce((total, b) => {
          if ($scope.model_filter && b.Name.toUpperCase().includes($scope.model_filter.toUpperCase())) { return total + b.Money; }
          else { return total; }
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result , use below option

1. Use scope variabled for filtered values

   ng-repeat="x in filteredValues = (records | filter: model_filter)"

2.Use ng-keyup to get filtered values on input field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model_filter" ng-keyup="calcTotal($event)">
```

3. In Key up event, calculate total again with filtered values

```
$scope.calcTotal = function(e){
            $scope.Total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filtered.length; i++) {
                     $scope.Total += $scope.filtered[i].Money;

            }
          }
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KjPrvr

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  name:
<input type="text" ng-model="model_filter" ng-keyup="calcTotal($event)">
  <hr/>
    <table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in filteredValues = (records | filter: model_filter)">
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Money | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            <td>{{Total | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
          $scope.calcTotal = function(e){
            $scope.Total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredValues.length; i++) {
                     $scope.Total += $scope.filteredValues[i].Money;
              
            }
          }
            $scope.records = [
                {
                    "Name": "Rodrigo",
                    "Money": 10
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Rodrigo",
                    "Money": 25
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Arnodl",
                    "Money": 15
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Carlos",
                    "Money": 5
                }
            ]
            $scope.Total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.records.length; i++) {
                     $scope.Total += $scope.records[i].Money;
              
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Issue from your code:**
Calculating total on $scope.records which remains same always event with filter and without filter
Total is getting calculated on intial load with $scope.records and not with filter